# django FilteredSelectMultiple widget request.POST shows items in order i added them - form.cleaned_data sorts them

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

Without any better idea for a good widget for picking items from a set and specifying what order you want them in, I'm playing around with Django Admin's FilteredSelectMultiple widget.

In my view, when I receive the form submission, I dumped request.POST and the various form.cleaned_data fields and discovered the following:

```
<QueryDict: {
    u'conditions': [u'2', u'1'], <-- this is the actual order I specified
   ...
}>
[<Condition: cond1>, <Condition: cond2>] <-- cleaned conditions
[07/Mar/2016 12:41:04] "POST /test_app/site/1/bulk_add_participants HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

In response.POST's QueryDict, the conditions are in the proper order: [2,1], but when *cleaned* they get sorted as [1,2] (I know for a fact that cond1.id=1 and cond2.id=2),

The queryset I used for my FilteredSelectMultiple sorts them by name, but I didn't expect the cleaned_data to be sorted that way. Perhaps that's what's going on.

I *suppose* I don't actually need the cleaned value as long as I know that `form.valid()` succeeded, provided the QueryDict is correct. All I need is the ids in the order I selected.

Does anyone know if the raw order of the items in request.POST is **guaranteed** to be in the same order of the items in the right box when I click submit? If not, is anyone aware of a Django widget which would better suit my needs?

BTW, for anyone whose curious, I'm working on a bulk create form.  I need to allow the user to create participants 1-1000 for an experiment and as I create the participants, I'll do an `itertools.cycle()` over whichever subset of that experiment's conditions in whatever order they specified,  mapping that condition ordering across the newly created participants.